# for cycle in assembler for PIC18F

Tags: assembly, pic

I have this code and I want to calculate how many instructions the `for cycle` takes to complete

```
while(1)
{
  // some instructions

  for (int i = 0; i < 107; i++)
  {
        // some code
        LATEbits.LATE2 = 1;
  }
  // other instructions
}
```

This is the disassembly listing

```
... some instructions
109:                   for (int i = 0; i < 107; i++)
654E  0E00     MOVLW 0x0
6550  0100     MOVLB 0x0
6552  6FD8     MOVWF 0xD8, BANKED
6554  0E00     MOVLW 0x0
6556  6FD7     MOVWF i, BANKED
6558  0100     MOVLB 0x0
655A  BFD8     BTFSC 0xD8, 7, BANKED
655C  D008     BRA 0x656E
655E  0100     MOVLB 0x0
6560  51D8     MOVF 0xD8, W, BANKED
6562  E10A     BNZ 0x6578
6564  0E6B     MOVLW 0x6B
6566  0100     MOVLB 0x0
6568  5DD7     SUBWF i, W, BANKED
656A  B0D8     BTFSC STATUS, 0, ACCESS
656C  D005     BRA 0x6578
6570  0100     MOVLB 0x0
6572  4BD7     INFSNZ i, F, BANKED
6574  2BD8     INCF 0xD8, F, BANKED
6576  D7F0     BRA 0x6558
110:                   {
111:                       LATEbits.LATE2 = 1;
656E  848D     BSF LATE, 2, ACCESS
112:                       
113:                   }  
... other instructions
```

My understanding is that at the first cycle the instructions from `0x654E` to `0x655C` are executed. At `0x655C` there is an unconditional branch which puts me inside the `for cycle` at `0x656E`. Now after that instruction is completed  how can the code keep looping if there are no other branches `BRA` that puts the code back to the beginning of the cycle?

Comment: Your assembly listing has been reordered to match the source that it has inlined, and this is unhelpful and confusing. After 656E it probably executes to 6570 which increments i then jumps back to 6558, until the conditional jump at 6562 eventually exits the loop. 6570-6576 are part of the `for` construction which is probably why it's moved them above the LATEbits set in the disassembly.

Comment: @Rup thank you now it is more clear. I still can't understand how it can reach `6562` though. It would execute 656E, 6570-6576 -> 6558-655C ->656E over again. How can it reach 6562?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'd missed that. The key is the [`BTFSC`](http://technology.niagarac.on.ca/staff/mboldin/18F_Instruction_Set/BTFSC.html) instruction, particularly the 'SC' part: skip the next instruction if the bit is clear. I can't follow exactly which variables it's testing at first glance but there must be a state where a BTFSC skips over the unconditional jump BRA at 655C to reach 655E.